# True/ False differential equation

Tags: calculus

Are the statements in Problems 46-54 true or false?

1. If $F(x)$ is an antiderivative of $f(x)$, then $y=F(x)$ is a solution to the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x)$.
2. If $y=F(x)$ is a solution to the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x)$, then $F(x)$ is an antiderivative of $f(x)$.
3. There is only one solution $y(t)$ to the initial value problem 
   $\frac{dy}{dx} = 3t^2, y(1) = \pi$

My answer:

The first two questions seems to be both true, I am 100% that the 2nd is true but the first makes me not sure.

The third question I would say yes, why? because I solved for C

$$ y=t^3+C $$

$$ \pi=1^3+C $$

$$ C=\pi-1 $$
Therefore, I would say it has only one solution. Am I right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answers are all correct.

> 1) If F(x) is an antiderivative of f(x), then y=F(x) is a solution to the differential equation dy/dx=f(x).

**True** because:

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = f(x) \rightarrow dy = f(x)dx \rightarrow \int dy = \int f(x)dx \Rightarrow y = \int f(x)dx$$

$$\text{Since they've told us }F(x) = \int f(x) \text{, we can substitute } F(x) \text{ for } \int f(x)dx \text{,}$$

$$ \text{ which leaves: } y = F(x) $$

> 2) If y=F(x) is a solution to the differential equation dy/dx=f(x), then F(x) is an antiderivative of f(x).

**True** because we can also work backwards from above. When we solve for $y$ in the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx} = f(x)$ we get $y = \int f(x)$, since we already know that $ y = F(x) $ based on the given information, we can say $y = y$ and $F(x) = \int f(x)$.

> 3) There is only one solution y(t) to the initial value problem dy dt = 3t2 , y(1) = π.

**True.** The authors were trying to lead you to this solution with the previous two questions. If we set the problem up:

$$  \frac{dy}{dt} = 3t^2 $$

$$ dy = 3t^2dt $$

$$ \int dy = \int 3t^2dt $$

$$ y = t^3 + C $$

We know that $y(1) = \pi$, so we can solve for C as you did.

$$ \pi = (1)^3 + C \rightarrow C = \pi - 1 \Rightarrow y = t^3 + \pi - 1$$

This means there's only one solution for any $t$ in the function $y(t)$.

Answer (score 5):

For questions 1 and 2, I would think your answers are correct.  In order to be doubly sure, check your textbook for the *definition* of an anti-derivative.

For your last question, your answer is right; there is indeed a unique solution to the initial value problem.

However, strictly speaking, the reasoning you've provided is insufficient.  You've shown that there is *an* answer, but not that the answer you've provided is the only answer.  You should have some statement in the textbook that initial value problems such as these have a unique solution.

Sometimes this result is bunched in with the [Picard-Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem).  In order to be strictly correct, check your textbook, and cite the relevant result.

Comment: Thaaaaaaaanks (Y)